# Running powershell script with gsutil cp to GCP shows upload progress on multiple lines

Tags: powershell, gsutil

I have a simple powershell script that runs from Task Scheduler on my Win'2008R2 system which basically just runs the following command:

> gsutil -o GSUtil:parallel_composite_upload_component_size=0 cp -L
>   C:\logs\log1.txt C:\archive\*.zip gs://temp

I'm using Start-Transcript to record the output to the results.log file. The problem is that when it's uploading the zip files to gcp it keeps recording the progress on multiple rows after every 64KB during the upload:

```
Resuming upload for file://E:\db\db1.zip
Uploading   gs://temp/db1.zip:             0 B/1.20 GiB
Uploading   gs://temp/db1.zip:             98.75 MiB/1.20
Uploading   gs://temp/db1.zip:             98.81 MiB/1.20
...and keeps repeating this until it uploads the entire 1.20 GB.
```

Since the results.log file is then being emailed to a group of people I don't need them to see all this junk. Showing just one line of it with the final file size would suffice.

When I run the command or script from a windows command prompt (or from native powershell) using: *powershell.exe -file c:\scripts\upload.ps1* then it works as expected showing the progress on a single line:

```
Resuming upload for file://E:\db\db1.zip
Uploading   gs://temp/db1.zip:             1.20 GiB/1.20 GiB
```

Before, when I was running the same command without the '-o GSUtil:parallel_composite_upload_component_size=0' parameter it was showing me the same long output but once I added this to gsutil I thought it was fine since it doesn't repeat the progress anymore on a bunch of lines in the PS command prompt. So it only happens when I run the script from Task Scheduler.

Any ideas why this is happening and how can I get around this?

Comment: The output you receive is correct. What you see in the command prompt for "progress" *is* the multiple messages, just that they are being overwritten on the same line over and over which makes it "seem" like it's a single line entry when in the actual case it's multiple output statements (ala. captured in your transcript file). The only way around it is if there is a switch in the program to not output progress, but just finished transfers.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp#parallel-composite-uploads Check out this. Apparently, the -L switch is so the program can pick up where it left off. So, there won't be a switch for making it a single line for each file uploaded. It should be possible to write a script to filter your log file though. Does it ever change to Uploaded or Complete, something like that?

Comment: I'm currently trying to filter it out into a $file string...I have something like this so far:

$file = @(Get-Content -Path $Log).
    Where({ $_.Trim() -notin $pattern1 + $pattern2 })

- but not sure how to keep only the 1st and last "Uploading" rows of the upload progress. So I think I'd need to make pattern something like: $pattern1=@('Uploading*') which I've tried but it only finds the line if it matches the line in the log exactly. Wildcards don't work.

Comment: @Patrick Mcvay: No it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [an open feature request in the gsutil repository, issue #481](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/481), to disable the progress spinner when the output is directed to something that isn't an interactive terminal.

Comment: Thanks I didn't see that before. For now I'll have to filter out all lines that have "Uploading  gs:* out of my string.